# How to provide rest api configuration or manifest as swagger json for soap ui to parse rest endpoints?

Tags: rest, web-services, soapui

I am trying to implement Soap ui for automating testing of my Rest web service. I found out that we have to either provide the service url or provide a manifest file like swagger.json to soap ui. 
My requirement is i want Soap Ui to get all of my rest endpoints without supplying it one by one. Now my question is, Is json file like swagger.json the only option for supplying endpoints config to Soap Ui.
In short, I want to know the enterprise level approach for soap ui implementations for automation testing of Restful web services.

Comment: I'm not sure which version of SoapUI you're using, so this comment is applicable to what I see in ReadyAPI 2.7.0 (Pro).  With 2.7.0, you can create endpoints from a swagger file, WSDL, WADL or manually one by one.  From reading your question, it looks like you are testing your own Rest web service.  If so, if you be worth looking to see if you can generate a WSDL/WADL and then import that in SoapUI.  I've used WSDL files to create a new project in SoapUI and it works very well.  It creates all of the endpoints, sample requests and a test suite for each endpoint.

Comment: Additional comment to what @ChrisAdams said: WSDL is normally provided by a SOAP service, whereas WADL or (the more popular?) Swagger are provided by a REST service. Further, SoapUI is also able to read a Postman collection, although that has to be (normally) created manually as well.